# get generated sql from a compiled linq query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, compiled-query

Is it possible to get the generated SQL from a compiled linq query?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can:

1. Use the log property of the context to redirect the generated query to the output window of Visual Studio. [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/claeyskurt/archive/2009/04/15/131232.aspx)
2. Or use the LINQ to SQL Debug Visualizer. [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/31/linq-to-sql-debug-visualizer.aspx)

Comment: redirecting the log to Visual Studio output was the easier way. Thumbs up

Comment: For the benefit of future googlers. I couldn't find anything relevant to the question on the first link. The content must have changed since this answer was posted. You basically add `db.Log = Console.Out;` where db is your database context object. [see source on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386961.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Use [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) :

Or alternatively get use sql server profiler to watch the query. I know you used to be able to however over the query variable in debug and it would show you the query it is going to execute but I am not entirely sure if that still works (Definitely not on client side apps)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks jfs, but the link in your option #1 is not good anymore. It is not showing any relevant article. Chris B's link to the MSDN article helped me.

Here is my solution since mine is not a Console application:

```
TextWriter tw = new StringWriter();
db.Log = tw;
IQueryable<Customer> custQuery =
    from cust in db.Customers
    where cust.City == "London"
    select cust;

string output = tw.ToString();   
// output variable has the generate SQL now
```